# In the adb shell, executing the exit command will kill the background script in android Q system

Tags: shell, adb

1. I run a adb shell script in background,for example:
   sh /data/test.sh &. the thread pid is 2442
2. After that, I run the exit command. The background script thread will be killed.

I don't know how to fix the problem.

shell background thread should ignore the SIGHUP signal.

---

more info:

```
ps -A | grep -E "2442|1007|978"                                                       
root           978     1  134760   4860 poll_schedule_timeout 0 S adbd

root          1007   978   33492   2916 sigsuspend          0 S sh

root          2442  1007   33492   3168 0                   0 R sh
```

I fetch signal:

```
 # strace -p 2442                                                  
strace: Process 2442 attached
--- SIGHUP {si_signo=SIGHUP, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=1007, si_uid=0} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[RTMIN]})            = 264
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD RTMIN], [RTMIN], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [RTMIN], [CHLD RTMIN], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD RTMIN], [RTMIN], 8) = 0
madvise(0x74a7648000, 4096, MADV_DONTNEED) = 0
madvise(0x74a7624000, 4096, MADV_DONTNEED) = 0
fcntl(3, F_GETFD)                       = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
fcntl(4, F_GETFD)                       = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
fcntl(5, F_GETFD)                       = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
fcntl(6, F_GETFD)                       = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
fcntl(29, F_GETFD)                      = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
fcntl(30, F_GETFD)                      = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
fcntl(31, F_GETFD)                      = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(2)                                = 0
close(1)                                = 0
close(0)                                = 0
mprotect(0x74a8298000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
mprotect(0x74a8298000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x74a8298000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
mprotect(0x74a8298000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x74a8298000, 4096)              = 0
exit_group(129)                         = ?
+++ exited with 129 +++
```

and parent signal info:

```
strace -p 1007                                                  
strace: Process 1007 attached
read(0, "\4", 1)                        = 1
write(2, "^D\r\n", 4)                   = 4
ioctl(10, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or TCSETSW, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
write(2, "You have running jobs\n", 22) = 22
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD RTMIN], [RTMIN], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [RTMIN], [CHLD RTMIN], 8) = 0
ioctl(10, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=55, ws_col=102, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
ioctl(10, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or TCSETSW, {B38400 opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
read(0, "\n", 1)                        = 1
write(2, "\r\n", 2)                     = 2
ioctl(10, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or TCSETSW, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD RTMIN], [RTMIN], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [RTMIN], [CHLD RTMIN], 8) = 0
ioctl(10, TIOCGWINSZ, {ws_row=55, ws_col=102, ws_xpixel=0, ws_ypixel=0}) = 0
ioctl(10, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or TCSETSW, {B38400 opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
read(0, "\4", 1)                        = 1
write(2, "^D\r\n", 4)                   = 4
ioctl(10, SNDCTL_TMR_STOP or TCSETSW, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
kill(-2442, SIGHUP)                     = 0
--- SIGINT {si_signo=SIGINT, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[RTMIN]})            = 0
nanosleep({tv_sec=1, tv_nsec=0}, 0x7ff000fe60) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD RTMIN], [RTMIN], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [RTMIN], [CHLD RTMIN], 8) = 0
ioctl(10, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD RTMIN], [RTMIN], 8) = 0
madvise(0x7ec8048000, 4096, MADV_DONTNEED) = 0
madvise(0x7ec8024000, 4096, MADV_DONTNEED) = 0
fcntl(3, F_GETFD)                       = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
fcntl(4, F_GETFD)                       = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
fcntl(5, F_GETFD)                       = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
fcntl(6, F_GETFD)                       = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
fcntl(7, F_GETFD)                       = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
fcntl(8, F_GETFD)                       = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
fcntl(9, F_GETFD)                       = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
fcntl(10, F_GETFD)                      = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)
close(10)                               = 0
fcntl(11, F_GETFD)                      = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
fcntl(31, F_GETFD)                      = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
close(2)                                = 0
close(1)                                = 0
close(0)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7ec8b48000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
mprotect(0x7ec8b48000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7ec8b48000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
mprotect(0x7ec8b48000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7ec8b48000, 4096)              = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Comment: That's normal -- if you close your terminal, stdin, stdout and stderr are no longer available, so any program with those file descriptors open is going to misbehave. Not specific to Android at all.

Comment: `yourprog </dev/null >/dev/null 2>/dev/null & disown -h` is going to help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `nohup` command, thus:

```
nohup command
```

This tells Android not to kill the process with SIGHUP. Run `nohup --help` for more information.